# Close UIWebView using javascript:window.close();

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5, uiwebview

The question sounds weird, but here is my case.

I have a `UIWebView` in my `UIView` ( done by `[self.view addSubview:webView];` ) which occupies full screen. It intentionally hides the `UIView` before the `UIWebView` clicks on an action `javascript:window.close();`.

How do I associate JavaScript in `UIWebView` page to `UIView`'s action , e.g. `[webView removeFromSuperView];` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible:

Set the location to something with your own scheme in the url, i.e.

document.location.href = "myscheme://DoSomething"

This will cause the UIWebViewDelegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest: to be called with an NSURLRequest parameter whose scheme is"myscheme". So you look for this scheme and extract the DoSomething and then act on the DoSomething, which in your case would be to call remove from superView.

(In the UIWebView dealloc probably need to make sure you call stopLoading)

Comment: sounds that it would work. Let me make a test & get back to you guys.

Comment: Success! Actually no need to use URL Scheme. Just make a pattern in URL, then read the pattern in `[NSURL path]` by `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`. Handle the pattern with different logic (you can even pass variables with query string ( of coz , POST values cannot be read ).