# window.close(); for closing UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript in UIWebView callback to C/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c)

I have an application which has a UIwebView with and its delegate methods in that one URL has source like

```
button onclick="window.close();">Close Me
```

and when I click on that not any of delegate method called.

How can I get that button close me clicked?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843736/ios-close-uiwebview-using-javascriptwindow-close for a way of notifying the delegate.

Comment: That answer will help i guess, but i cant get how it use in my code, can u plz help for that ?