# Returning to Native app from webview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I am new to iOS development and I am creating an app with a webview which has a native login screen. When finished I need to close the webview and return to the native login screen. I have seen this question answered but I do not understand the answer. this is the answered post: [Close UIWebView using javascript:window.close();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843736/close-uiwebview-using-javascriptwindow-close)

I currently have this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mysite/redirector.php"];
NSString *postData =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[_txtUsername text],[_txtPassword text]];
// Create the request object
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [postData dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// create the web view
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
//Change Frame
webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y + 20,  webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height);

// Load the request
[webView loadRequest: request];

//show the webview
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

What would I need to change in the above code to make this work?

How do I "read the pattern in `[NSURL path]` by `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992339/how-to-intercept-button-click-inside-uiwebview-on-ios. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might do the trick, but I have added the code on that page, but when I click close nothing happens, Do I have to modify the code above at all to make this work?

Comment: You can remove web view from its super view if button clicked. Put [webView removeFromSuperView] inside webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: with the URL check.

Comment: Sorry I am totally new to this, do I put the [webView removeFromSuperView] inside the if statement where it says //do capture action? because its complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below things in your code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mysite/redirector.php"];
                NSString *postData =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[_txtUsername text],[_txtPassword text]];
                // Create the request object
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
                [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
                [request setHTTPBody: [postData dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // create the web view
                UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
                //Change Frame
                webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y + 20, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height);

                //assign delegate to webview

                  webView.delegate = self.

                // Load the request
                [webView loadRequest: request];

                //show the webview
                [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

//and also implement below delegate method

```
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
     [webView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

//If you want to close webview when link clicked then used below code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

//Webview link press is hyperlink then it will called
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){

        [webView removeFromSuperView];
    }

    return YES;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, is this automatically closing the webview when its finished loading? I need it to close when a hyperlink is pushed. Can I achieve this using this?

Comment: yes because "webViewDidFinishLoad" is a delegate method and as soon as you data is finished to load this will call automatically. so in this method we remove webview from supper view so it was close automatically

Comment: I need it to close when a Hyperlink is pressed not automatically. Thank you for your input tho :).

Comment: Hi Dipen, thankyou for your help with this, I dont want it to open an external site, I want it to close the webview and return to the inital and only segue that has an ID of Login when the hyperlink with a href of "closewebview:" is clicked.

Comment: see my edited answer, you have added webview in login view cotroller right ?

Comment: I am getting an error on the webview.delegate = self; : Assigning to 'id(UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_string     Also i need it when a specific link is clicked not just any link. Thanks again for your help.